# Bump material for landscape too flat

Tags: texturing, materials, normal-map

I'm trying to add a dirt texture with small rocks as a foundation for a landscape, but I have a familiar problem: when the camera is directly overhead, the texture looks 3 dimensional.  However, when looking horizontally, it goes flat.  How do I make it bump at all angles?  I should mention there is a colour image in the image texture input node going into the colour input of the principled shader as well as a height image in the bump and roughness).

**Here's the overhead view:**

[image]

**Here's the horizontal:**

[image]

**Here's the node setup:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it looks like a *Bump* or *Normal* map won't be enough to give a 3D effect. You can use the *micro-displacement* method as explained by Valentin (never tried) or you can use the *Displacement* modifier:

- *Subdivide* your ground so that you will be able to deform the surface.
- Give it a *Displacement* modifier.
- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier so that it will smooth the effect. Choose a *Subdivision* value of 2.
- Also, on the <kbd>T</kbd> (Tools) panel > *Tools* > *Edit* > *Shading*, press *Smooth*.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Texture*, choose *Displace* in the top dropdown menu, and in *Image* load the DISP picture you've used in the *Node Editor* (in the *Image Texture* node before the *Bump* node), but maybe even your color texture will be ok.
- In the *Displace* modifier make sure the good texture is selected, play with the *Strength* value to find the right amount of effect.

[image]

Comment: This worked!  Thanks!  Too bad it has to be more subdivisions and polygons, but it is much more realistic looking

Comment: To recreate this kind of soil with much less polygons, you could also create a grainy soil with a picture and a simple Bump node (like you've done before but with a different picture with no big rock), then create 2 or 3 low-poly 3D rocks, link-duplicated them (alt D), scale them up or down, rotate them, and put them on your ground.

Comment: Ah this is a good idea!  I have a small rock pack already but I could maybe use them as a particle system and scatter them with a bump texture.  The only thing is that it would still have to be covered significantly enough I would think to avoid showing the inevitable flatness

Comment: Yes I also thought about particle system, you really need to test these different solutions to see which one fits the best

Comment: That is incredible. That beats laborious node compositing.

Answer (score 4):

The best way achieve a "bump" from all angles is using micro-displacement.

Replace your *Bump* node with a *Math* node and set it to *Multiply*. Then connect the Math node with the *Displacement* input of your *Shader Output* node. Play with your Multiply value to get the result that fits your scene.

This will not work until you add extra geometry to the plane. The most efficient way to do that is using a *Subsurf modifier*. Set it to *Simple* so it doesn't smooth the plane and *Adaptive* so you get optimized memory and render times. If there's no option that says "Adaptive" you have to change from "Supprted" to *"Experimental"* feature set in the Renders tab under *"Render"*. Then down in the *Material tab* in the *Properties* under *"Settings"* set your Displacement to either *"Both"* or *"True"*. "Both" gives you the option to still add a bump map on top of your displacement.

Then you can enter rendered view and enjoy your displacement! Note that the displacement doesn't update in rendered view. Switch from and back to rendered view to refresh the displacement.

Comment: Hm for some reason I keep running out of memory when I use the adaptive feature.  Does this require a significant amount of memory?

Comment: Does your plane already have more than the initial four vertices?

Comment: yup it was sub-divided several times and then had sub-surf

Comment: Then remove all subdivisions and only use the Adaptive Subdivisions. This should fix your memory problem. The advantage that  this method has over moonboot's is that Adaptive Subdivision should use less memory and render time with increased detail. There's an in-depth video on the subject from Blender Guru if you wanna check it out: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-microdisplacements?rq=displace.

Answer (score 0):

I have some pages from my scrapbooks that would greatly interest you. I took screenshots of nodes few months ago.

Check out page 94 in link below. 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kP0Dz1VFLIlgzykHcc00eIzvZoAtVO0okPSmD7CU1mo

This next page might be different: page 122 on broken tiles and debris on ground. 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ggss5H_XdWtIZ825iRuUjk7svvzdoPWM-cP1yv4kCCc